# What could be causing this android chrome glitching?

Tags: android, google-chrome

On some webpage this glitching is so frequent that makes chrome almost unusable. It happens a lot when I am on input box or scrolling down the page, and the fracture will

1. flash as cursor flash，or
2. turn weboage components into black or noise or has an overlapping black or
3. noise fracture on webpage.

[glitching looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyEEq.jpg)

I tried all the chrome trouble shooting methods online including reinstalling chrome, update chrome and keyboard to newest version, re-starting phone, turn off some chrome flags but it continues.

I have only noticed it on chrome. It happened suddenly without me messing with anything before.

Oneplus 9, colorOS v11.2